# How Alexa can find out my country if I'm using proxy?

Tags: proxy, ranking, alexa-internet

In Iran, Facebook has filtered by government for (at least) 3 years; so the only way to gaining access to Facebook is by proxy or VPN. In that way IP address that appears to websites is from another country.
My question is if no one can access to Facebook directly from Iran, how it can possible that Facebook is rank 6 in this country(http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/IR)? In other words, how Alexa can find out my country if I'm using proxy or VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Alexa collects a lot of data from their toolbar or other client-side plugins. This way, the users in Iran are telling them when they are accessing Facebook (and they do not need to have Facebook's cooperation to get to the stats). Kind of like the TV ratings, which are also not measured by what actually happens on the transmission channel (would be tough to do with broadcasts anyway), but by polling a (small, but hopefully significant) user base that allows themselves to be measured.

This also explains why they have (or at least present) other demographic data like your age, gender, and education status, which really cannot be derived from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what sort of proxies are used:

Quote from [Rfc2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> proxy
> An intermediary program which acts as both a server and a client
> for the purpose of making requests on behalf of other clients.
> Requests are serviced internally or by passing them on, with
> possible translation, to other servers. A proxy MUST implement
> both the client and server requirements of this specification. A
> **"transparent proxy" is a proxy that does not modify the request**
> or
> response beyond what is required for proxy authentication and
> identification. A "non-transparent proxy" is a proxy that
> modifies
> the request or response in order to provide some added service
> to
> the user agent, such as group annotation services, media type
> transformation, protocol reduction, or anonymity filtering.
> Except
> where either transparent or non-transparent behavior is
> explicitly
> stated, the HTTP proxy requirements apply to both types of
> proxies.

Another thing could be that country detection somehow takes other things into account.

Comment: Here, people usually use proxys like ultrasurf, freegate, yourfreedom, tor, etc; also many people using VPN.